# R Shiny as Windows Desktop App Creates Text File With Warning

Tags: r, desktop-application, shiny, portable-applications

I am a statistics student and I have created an app in R Shiny, went through all the steps described as per http://blog.analytixware.com/2014/03/packaging-your-shiny-app-as-windows.html and encounter the following issue: chrome portable does open, my app runs fine and I can use it, however a new file is created each time I press on vbs.run, it is named as some number i.e. 0.3928118 opening it in notepad yields the following:

`proc.time()
user system elapsed 
3.55 0.26 9.48`

However, in my code I do not use proc.time() function anywhere. When I try to delete the file - I cant do it unless I restart my pc. The error says : "The action can't be completed because the file is open in Google Chrome Portable". My run.vbs file looks like:

`Randomize
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave runShinyApp.R" & " " & RND & " ", 0, False`

My runShinyApp.R looks like:

`require(shiny,quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
require(shinyjs,quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
.libPaths("./R-Portable/App/R-Portable/library")
browser.path = file.path(getwd(),"GoogleChromePortable/GoogleChromePortable.exe")
options(browser = browser.path)
shiny::runApp("./Shiny/",port=8888,launch.browser= TRUE,quiet=TRUE)`

Note: I added lines 1 and 2 to runShinyApp.R because in that strange file I would also get Loading shiny...... note etc and this has removed them.

I would be very grateful if you could give me a hand with this as I have tried everything and spent weeks trying to make it work and I have no idea what is going wrong here...

Comment: Have you tried `suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(shiny,quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE))` ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Tutuchan. I get the following error when running it:

`Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8888
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
> proc.time()
   user  system elapsed 
   3.69    0.29    5.69`

Comment: That is strange. Does the app work correctly when launching it normally from R ?

Comment: @Tuchtan I added your suggested line to my runShinyApp.R and now I get
`Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8888
> proc.time()
   user  system elapsed 
   3.57    0.18    6.38 
`
So I got rid of the first line, but these two remain

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine from R

Comment: My runShinyApp.R :
`require(shiny,quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
.libPaths("./R-Portable/App/R-Portable/library")
# the path to portable chrome

browser.path = file.path(getwd(),"GoogleChromePortable/GoogleChromePortable.exe")
options(browser = browser.path)
shiny::runApp("./Shiny/",port=8888,launch.browser=TRUE)`

Comment: Well there must be a `proc.time()` somewhere in your application that you have to remove.
As for the `Listening on ...` message, use the `quiet` options in `runApp`.

Comment: I added quiet=TRUE and now in the file created there is nothing( when I open it with Note Pad there is an empty sheet). The file is named as some number i.e. this time "0.1424982". Re-running run.vbs yields a file with just `proc.time()` output - this function is not in my code. I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the relevant line in your VBScript code:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave runShinyApp.R" & " " & RND & " ", 0, False
```

When you run `R CMD BATCH foo.R` it produces an `foo.Rout` file by default which contains the information that you have reproduced (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html). You can test this by running `R CMD BATCH` on a simple R file.

In your case, the name of the outfile is specified using the `RND` VBScript function, which is why you are getting the random name. AFAICT, there is no way to not generate an outfile, and as long as the R batch process is running (which is as long as the Shiny session lasts), the file is locked, so you cannot delete it. You might check whether Shiny still works if you replace `R CMD BATCH` with [`Rscript`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html).

Unless you are worried about your end-user being spooked by the appearance of strange files on their machine, it is harmless, and you should probably not worry about its existence. You can change your VBScript to name it more recognizably if you want.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. App is not running when changing my vbs to `Randomize
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe Rscript --vanilla --slave runShinyApp.R" & " " & RND & " ", 0, False`
The reason why I want to get rid of that file is because I try to create a .exe file to run this vbs and this is not possible when a new file is created each time. Do you have any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: @Ivona Not `R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\R.exe Rscript` but `R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe`.

Comment: Now my **run.vs**:
`Randomize
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave runShinyApp.R" & " " & RND & " ", 0, False`
no file is created and app is not launched either.

Comment: @Ivona Exclude the `CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave`. Those are not parameters `Rscript` accepts.

Comment: It is working and I managed to deploy my app as .exe and create a windows launcher. Thank you so much for taking time to look into this and helping me to solve this issue that has been bugging me for weeks!

Comment: I also tried deploying R App using the new framework as per http://oddhypothesis.blogspot.com/2016/04/desktop-deployr.html - it has several advantages over the first one. And I get the same issue described [here](https://github.com/wleepang/DesktopDeployR/issues/3) in the last comment. Perhaps you have any idea how to fix this one?

Comment: @Ivona My suggestion would be to create a new question with the same details as in GH, and I will take a look. I think the primary difficulty with answering these questions is that none of this is very reproducible, as all of this is very platform specific.

Comment: Thank you, I created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698454/r-desktopdeployr-stop-logging-error)