# R Shiny DesktopDeployR Stop Logging Error

Tags: java, r, deployment, shiny

I am trying to deploy R Shiny App as an Windows Desktop App. So far I have used the framework described at http://blog.analytixware.com/2014/03/packaging-your-shiny-app-as-windows.html and managed to make it work with the help of stackoverflow users (question name "R Shiny as Windows Desktop App Creates Text File With Warning").

An update to this framework has been developed and it has several advantages over the previous one, such as not relying on Google Chrome browser etc. and it is described here: http://oddhypothesis.blogspot.com/2016/04/desktop-deployr.html 
All files can be found in the GitHub account of framework creator (link is presented in the description)

I have adjusted the following:

**app.R**

```
require(shinyjs,quietly = TRUE,warn.conflicts=FALSE)
require(markdown,quietly = TRUE,warn.conflicts=FALSE)
require(scales,quietly = TRUE,warn.conflicts=FALSE)
require(DT,quietly = TRUE,warn.conflicts=FALSE)
runApp("./app/shiny/", launch.browser=TRUE,quiet=TRUE)
```

**packages.txt**

Added the names of the packages I am using

```
    # Primary package dependencies for the application that are loaded during
    # startup.
    #
    # If not available, they will be installed into app/library.  Custom source
    # packages need to be installed manually.

    # bare miniminum: configurations are stored in json format
    jsonlite

    # if deploying shiny based applications:
    shiny
    shinyjs
    markdown
    scales
    DT
```

App does launch, it works. However a new folder is created called *log* with file *error.log*, which includes the following:

```
library paths:
... C:/Users/VoronecI/Desktop/New folder (2)/app/library
... C:/Users/VoronecI/Desktop/New folder (2)/dist/R-Portable/App/R-Portable/library
working path:
... C:/Users/VoronecI/Desktop/New folder (2)
Loading required package: methods
ensuring packages: jsonlite, shiny, shinyjs, markdown, scales, DT

Attaching package: 'shiny'

The following object is masked from 'package:jsonlite':

    validate


Attaching package: 'shinyjs'

The following object is masked from 'package:shiny':

    runExample

The following objects are masked from 'package:methods':

    removeClass, show


Attaching package: 'DT'

The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':

    dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
```

Is there a way to prevent this logging of the unmeaningful error? 
The reason why I want to get rid of it is because I further use *Inno Setup Compiler* to create *.exe* and this is not working when I have a log file updating each time I run the app.

Comment: All files and code needed for the framework is stored [here](https://github.com/wleepang/DesktopDeployR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this file (line 66) https://github.com/wleepang/DesktopDeployR/blob/7c81e72c5beb29bf84ca65fd1d5bb5486caec51a/dist/script/wsf/js/run.js

The command is run as

```
var strCommand = [Rexe, Ropts, RScriptFile, "1>", Outfile, "2>&1"].join(" ");
```

which redirects command line outputs (that normally directly print to the screen) to the `Outfile`. You can change this line to

```
var strCommand = [Rexe, Ropts, RScriptFile].join(" ");
```

which will disable the logging. This might have other implications though (you might see a command window for example, I am not too sure but test it out).

Alternatively, you might be able to change this file https://github.com/wleepang/DesktopDeployR/blob/7c81e72c5beb29bf84ca65fd1d5bb5486caec51a/app/config.cfg (line 27) and set

```
    - use_userprofile: true
```

(you need to uncomment this line, it is currently inside a block comment). This will make sure the log file goes into the user profile folder, and that might also solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to look into this. First solution removes error.log, but still creates folder log. Is there a way to get rid of that as well?

Comment: @Ivona Get rid of [line 37](https://github.com/wleepang/DesktopDeployR/blob/7c81e72c5beb29bf84ca65fd1d5bb5486caec51a/dist/script/wsf/js/run.js#L37).

Comment: Thank you so much, everything is working just the way I wanted it to! :)

Comment: Developer here. I'd suggest at least storing logs in the user profile. Otherwise, tracking down any application errors will be difficult/impossible.  I've also never had problems compiling a setup.exe with InnoSetup. Can you elaborate as to how the compiler is failing?

Comment: @oddHypothesis when I try and compile the app with InnoSetup, create installer, click on it - nothing happens. As soon as the log file is removed, it runs. Is it still inadvisable to  remove the log file even though I have tested the app in R environment and I am sure it does what it is supposed to do?

Comment: I should probably ask if there is a way for error.log to appear only if there is an actual error( i.e. not to let me know that packages are being loaded). Thanks

Comment: @Ivona: Just to clarify, the installer generated by InnoSetup does not run? Or the installed app does not run? Regarding what is logged, anything your app sends to stdout (e.g. print statements, etc) and stderr (messages, warnings, errors) is captured by the log. More granular control of logging is not currently available, but worth looking into.

Comment: Installer does run, the app doesn't. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Ivona, I just finished developing the [RInno](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno) package which also uses Inno Setup and the DesktopDeployR project to install local Shiny apps, and it will log errors without a problem.

To get started:

```
install.packages("RInno")
require(RInno)
RInno::install_inno()
```

Then you just need to call two functions to create an installation framework:

```
create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "path/to/myapp")
compile_iss()
```

If you are interested in other features, check out [FI Labs - RInno](http://www.ficonsulting.com/filabs/RInno). I'd be interested to know if turning off the error logging feature is something you would like to add ;)